# Deleting last element in an ordered linked list in C

Tags: c, list

I have a linked list that organizes the data in ascending order based on one of its values (each node has more than one variable saved).  I delete the node from the linked list based on a criteria.  Thing is, it works and it removes each node when the condition is met but when it comes to the last element it always crashes when it removes it and I have no idea why. I have searched everywhere for it and tried different approaches but non helped so

> I was hoping someone could tell me what is causing this crashing by looking at my code.

Here's my delete function:

```
void RemoveFromWaiting(wPtr *waitingPtr,int MinsToLand)
{
    wPtr previousPtr;
    wPtr currentPtr;
    wPtr tempPtr;

    if(MinsToLand == (*waitingPtr)->MinsToLand)
    {
        tempPtr=*waitingPtr;
        *waitingPtr=(*waitingPtr)->nextPtr;
        free(tempPtr);

    }
    else
    {
        previousPtr=*waitingPtr;
        currentPtr=(*waitingPtr)->nextPtr;

        while(currentPtr!=NULL && currentPtr->MinsToLand != MinsToLand)
        {
            previousPtr=currentPtr;
            currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }

        if(currentPtr!=NULL)
        {
            tempPtr=currentPtr;
            previousPtr->nextPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
            free(tempPtr);
        }
    }
}
```

If it is of any use here's the structure and the function that adds the values to the list in the first place:

```
struct WaitingList{
    char fdetails[10];
    int ArrivalTimeHours;
    int ArrivalTimeMins;
    int MinsToLand;
    int MinsForFuel;
    int passengers;
    struct WaitingList *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct WaitingList Waiting;
typedef Waiting *wPtr;

void AddToWaitList(wPtr *waitingPtr, char fdetails[], int ArrivalTimeHours, 
    int ArrivalTimeMins, int MinsToLand, int MinsForFuel, int passengers)
{
    wPtr newPtr;
    wPtr previousPtr;
    wPtr currentPtr;

    newPtr=malloc(sizeof(Waiting));

    if( newPtr!=NULL)
    {
        strncpy(newPtr->fdetails,fdetails,sizeof(Waiting));
        newPtr->ArrivalTimeHours=ArrivalTimeHours;
        newPtr->ArrivalTimeMins=ArrivalTimeMins;
        newPtr->MinsForFuel=MinsForFuel;
        newPtr->MinsToLand=MinsToLand;
        newPtr->passengers=passengers;
        newPtr->nextPtr=NULL;

        previousPtr=NULL;
        currentPtr=*waitingPtr;

        while(currentPtr!=NULL && MinsToLand > currentPtr->MinsToLand)
        {
            previousPtr=currentPtr;
            currentPtr=currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }

        if(previousPtr==NULL)
        {
            newPtr->nextPtr=*waitingPtr;
            *waitingPtr=newPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            previousPtr->nextPtr=newPtr;
            newPtr->nextPtr=currentPtr;
        }
    }
}
```

I basically delete one of the nodes when the variable `MinsToLand` entered to the function is equal to one of the same value in one of the nodes. My function does that already but when it's deleting the last element in crashes.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when the last element is deleted? You could have some "pointer to the first element" that goes to NULL. Or you could have a sentinel at the beginning of the list whose `next` goes to NULL. But you have to have some way to represent the fact that the list is empty, and I don't see how your code does that.

Comment: The line `strncpy(newPtr->fdetails,fdetails,sizeof(Waiting));` is surely using the wrong size...

Comment: Do you initialize your list with a NULL pointer at the start of your program?

Comment: Yes I do, sorry forgot to put the code for it

Comment: @DavidSchwartz he has a pointer to (typedeffed) pointer, but does not exploit its full potential.

Comment: I cannot see anything in your code which would cause an error when the last element of a list is deleted. But it will definitely crash if you give it an empty list (ie: one with *waitingPtr = NULL) which could happen depending on the rest of your code.

Comment: It appears your difficulty deleting the last node is set in motion when you call `AddToWaitList` for your *first* node. Any time you create/delete the *first* node, you must pass the *pointer address* of your list to the function where the creation occurs. Otherwise, you are simply operating on a *copy* of the pointer passed. When you go to removed the last (*first*) node, you most likely receive a segmentation fault. I suspect if you examine your `next`, `prev` chain of pointers for your list, you will find a stray pointer surrounding your first node. Step through it carefully.

Comment: Can someone post the code? I am seriously confused :/

Comment: Here is an annotated example of a [**singly-linked circular list**](http://pastebin.com/BirWtkvb) that should help. Look at `void delete_list (lline *list)`, and `void delete_node (lline **list, size_t nth)`. Also look at `lline *insert_node (lline **list, char *s, size_t n)` and `lline *create_node (char *s, size_t n)`

Comment: With what arguments are you calling `AddToWaitList` and `RemoveFromWaiting`?